# When can one use implicit braces instead of explicit braces?

Tags: tex-core, implicit-braces

For context, an implicit character is a control sequence that has been `\let` to a character. For example, both plain TeX and LaTeX use `\let\bgroup{ \let\egroup}` making `\bgroup` and `\egroup` into implicit braces.

In some places, TeX accepts either, in other places, it does not. For example, implicit braces cannot be used to collect tokens for undelimited macro arguments, nor can they be used to delimit the replacement text of a macro assignment.

Implicit braces can be used

- to form groups: `\bgroup...\egroup`;
- to construct boxes: `\hbox`, `\vbox`, and `\vtop`;
- to create vertical material with `\insert` or `\vadjust`;
- for alignment material with `\halign`, `\valign`, and `\noalign`; and
- to create a new math atom.

Implicit *left* braces—which must be matched with literal characters with category code 2 (e.g., `}2`)—can be used

- to assign to token variables;
- with `\hyphenation` and `\patterns`;
- to change case with `\uppercase` and `\lowercase`;
- to write messages using `\message` or `\errmessage`;
- to write files using `\write`;
- to construct a `\special`;
- for `\mark`;
- for `\discretionary`; and
- for a four-way `\mathchoice`.

I tried to be thorough, but TeX is extremely complicated. Are there any other places where an implicit brace can be used instead of an explicit one?

Comment: I can try to answer this, but it may be easier to list the cases where implicit braces may *not* be used.

Comment: Sure. I added a few more where they are allowed. The most obvious one I missed being token variables.

Comment: I would add "to delimit a subscript or superscript in math mode", e.g., `$a_\bgroup b\egroup$`

Comment: @Bruno: That's creating a new math atom, I think. (I'd  have to reread Appendix G to be sure.)

Comment: I think that you are right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In TeX82,

Explicit left braces are required: to start the body of a macro definition: `\def`, `\edef`, `\xdef`, `\gdef`, and when a token list should be tucked into a single token.

Explicit right braces are required whenever a token list must end, including the case where a token list should be tucked into a single token.

Primitives that need a token list argument:

- `\def`, `\edef`, `\xdef`, `\gdef`
- `\mark`
- `\message`, `\errmessage`
- `\uppercase`, `\lowercase`
- `\write`
- `\special`
- `\patterns`, but only in the special erroneous case of extra `\patterns` in initex after typesetting has already started (other uses of are happy with an implicit right brace).

Assignments that need a token list argument:

- `\toks`, `\output`, `\everypar`, `everymath`, `\everydisplay`, `\everyhbox`, `\everyvbox`, `\everyjob`, `\everycr`, `\errhelp`

As far as I can make out, these are all the cases in TeX82. The new extended typesetting engines will have longer primitive lists for explicit right braces, but the same basic rule about closing a token list will apply.

Comment: Btw, I would never have found that odd \patterns case if I had not looked into the web source itself.

Comment: What an odd case!

Comment: Side note, implicit left brace might be used in \def (bug) (see B952 in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581118/whats-new-in-tex-version-3-141592653/582738#582738)