# When might it be helpful to use implicit braces instead of explicit braces?

Tags: tex-core, implicit-braces

We've covered the question ["When can one use implicit braces instead of explicit braces?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/when-can-one-use-implicit-braces-instead-of-explicit-braces); this leads immediately in my mind to the question "Why would one want to?"

(Remember, implicit braces are e.g. `\bgroup` and `\egroup` as defined by the code `\let\bgroup={ \let\egroup=}` in plain TeX.)

I suppose this is basically the same as the question "When must one use implicit braces instead of explicit braces?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a nice example in Appendix E of the TeXbook, where a letter format is described. A few lines of a possible letter:

```
\address
Prof.~Brian~K. Reid
Department of Electrical Engineering
Stanford University
Stanford, CA 94305

\body
```

Here, `\address` and `\body` are defined as follows:

```
\def\address{\beginlinemode\getaddress}
{\obeylines\gdef\getaddress #1
  #2
  {#1\gdef\addressee{#2}%
    \global\setbox\theaddress=\vbox\bgroup\raggedright%
    \hsize=\longindentation \everypar{\hangindent2em}#2
    \def\endmode{\egroup\endgroup \copy\theaddress \bigskip}}}
\def\body{\beginparmode}
\def\beginparmode{\endmode
  \begingroup\parskip=\medskipamount
  \def\endmode{\par\endgroup}}
```

Please pay attention mainly to the `\vbox\bgroup` in `\getaddress` and to the `\egroup` in `\endmode` that gets called by `\beginparmode` via `\body`. What happens is that `\address` starts a `\vbox`, which is then ended by the occurence of `\body` (or anything else calling `\endmode`). The box thus constructed can then be used "both in the letter and in the label on the envelope", as Knuth explains.

Comment: So it breaks if you try to put the body before the address, or if you try to put something before the body but after the address? Seems like a potential cause of future confusion..

Answer (score 8):

For example, you can do this:

```
\def\blah{\bgroup\bf}
\def\bloh{\egroup}

not bold \blah bold\bloh not bold
```

Doing this:

```
\def\blah{{\bf}
\def\bloh{}}
```

would have completely different result.

Comment: I'd call this an example of structure-defining macros.  The question is, why not define `\def\blahbloh#1{{\bf #1}}`?  It's an example of the mechanical difference, but not an example of why they are useful.

Comment: @Charles: As DEK points out on p. 205 in the TeXbook, this can be useful if you don't want to fill TeX's memory with a long argument. He even gives an example with `\beginbold` and `\endbold`, but I think nowadays this would only be useful if you have _lots_ of pages in bold.

Comment: On the other hand, one *could* just use `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` for this and avoid having to do so much thinking, right?

Comment: Oh, and this doesn't leave a space between "bold" and "not"...

Comment: @SamB: just leave a space before `\bloh`. --- Note that replacing `\bgroup` by `\iftrue{\else}\fi`, and `\egroup` by `\iffalse{\else}\fi` will also work :).

Comment: @Bruno: I know how to fix it, I was just pointing out an apparant mistake I had just noticed in examining the code. (What, did you think I had actually *tried* it or something?) I am, however, not entirely certain that spaces are treated in the same manner between bold/non-bold text...

Answer (score 7):

Among a gazillion other uses, it provides a handy way for storing paragraphs in a box for later processing.

```
\newbox\savedparbox
\def\saveparbox{\par\begingroup
  \def\par{\egroup\endgroup}
  \global\setbox\savedparbox\vbox\bgroup}

Ordinary paragraph.
\saveparbox
This paragraph will be saved in \string\box\string\savedparbox.
If you wish, you can unpack the box and do all kinds of processing on it.
In this demo, I won't do any processing.
Look in the log file to examine the box contents.

\showboxdepth=99
\showboxbreadth=999
\showbox\savedparbox

Another ordinary paragraph.
\bye
```

Answer (score 6):

When testing for the presence of a brace using a `\futurelet` construction.

```
\makeatletter
\def\isbraced{\futurelet\next\isbraced@}
\def\isbraced@{\ifx\next\bgroup Braced\else Unbraced\fi}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside macros, `\bgroup` sometimes helps readability:

```
\def\IntroEntry#1#2%
 {\blank[line]
  \begingroup
    \setupalign[right]
    \setuptolerance[verytolerant]
    \setupindenting[no]
    \switchtobodyfont[9pt]
    \ss 
    \begingroup
      \bf #1\par 
    \endgroup
    #2\par
  \endgroup }
```

(I tend to get confused when there are too many braces)

Comment: If you use \begingroup instead of \bgroup, you get a compile-time check as well.

Comment: edited (but I usually use \bgroup because I am too lazy to type any more)

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should have restricted my question to cases not already covered by `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\def\A{%
  \bgroup
  \B}
\def\B{C\egroup}

\begin{document}
\A
\end{document}
```

in this case it maybe better to use `\begingroup ...\endgroup` instead