# Showcase of brace tricks: }, \egroup, \iffalse{\fi}, etc.

Tags: tex-core, big-list, braces

There have been a few questions about braces recently, specifically about when to use them (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9827/when-might-it-be-helpful-to-use-implicit-braces-instead-of-explicit-braces) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/when-can-one-use-implicit-braces-instead-of-explicit-braces) question). *Note: I had mistakenly stated that SamB was the author of both questions.*

But there are other ways to get token lists that behave like braces. For instance,

```
{ and 
}

\let\bgroup{ and 
\let\egroup}

\def\Egroup{\iffalse{\fi}} and 
\def\Bgroup{\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi}

\def\bbgroup{\expandafter{\ifnum0=`}\fi} and
\def\eegroup{\ifnum0=`{\fi}}
```

Of course, this is not a complete list. It would be nice to have a showcase of typical situations where one can/should use each. Share on any brace hack that appears in your macros, or in packages that you've written/read about/used...

I guess one hack per answer.

Comment: An explanation of `\alignsafe@testopt` in amsmath.sty would be great. (In the `dtx` they say "Testing for an optional argument can be really, really tricky in certain complicated contexts.")

Comment: @Bruno: Can you please explain the `\expandafter`s in `\Bgroup` and `\bbgroup`? I don't see what changes if the `\expandafter`s are omitted.

Comment: @Hendrik: They are needed so that `\Bgroup` and `\bbgroup`actually expand to an open brace when hit from the left by expansion. For instance, `\expandafter\somemacro\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi` will grab the rest of the current brace group. I think that it should be possible to use it for an expandable `\afterbracegroup`. See my answer below for another use.

Answer (score 16):

A nice example of using a `\iffalse{\fi` trick was posted by Dan Luecking on comp.text.tex in the thread [Capilatizing the first character](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/48306c1b9fa29576) with a complete explanation. It's a macro that takes a string as argument and defines a macro `\Fcap` which contains the same string but with the first letter upper-cased (e.g. `test` becomes `Test`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\FirstcapD#1#2\delimiter{%%% Delimited
   \iffalse{\fi
   \uppercase{\edef\Fcap{\iffalse}\fi#1}#2}}%
\begin{document}
\FirstcapD test\delimiter
\ttfamily\meaning\Fcap
\end{document}
```

shows that `\Fcap` is `macro:->Test` i.e. the upper-case version of the argument `test`. I reproduce here the explanation of how the code works. As the macro is delimited, `\FirstcapD test\delimiter` will make `#1`=`t` and `#2`=`est`.

The first `\iffalse{\fi` is just here to have a balanced number of braces inside the definition of `\Firstcap`, but as `\iffalse` is always false, it disappears during expansion.

Then `\uppercase{\edef\Fcap{\iffalse}\fi#1}` is executed with `#1 = t`. The `\uppercase{\edef\Fcap{\iffalse}\fi t}` thus becomes `\edef\Fcap{\iffalse}\fi T` (the `t` has been upper-cased).

At this stage, we have `\edef\Fcap{\iffalse}\fi Test}` because `#2` is `est`. This code is not balanced in braces, but that doesn't matter as `\edef` expands as it reads. Because `\iffalse` is always false, the `\iffalse}\fi` disappears, and what remains is just `\edef\Fcap{Test}`.

Answer (score 15):

I'm going to give a try at Hendrik's suggestion of explaining `\alignsafe@testopt`. The problem was reported in the LaTeX bug database as [amslatex/1834](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=amslatex/1834) (it's now fixed) with the follow-up [latex/3040](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/3040). The problem arises in the following situation (`{aligned}` immediately followed by a `&` and inside a tabular-like environment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter\let\alignsafe@testopt\@testopt\makeatother % reactivates the bug
\begin{document}
\begin{align}\begin{aligned}
&b=d%% Problem: First nonspace token found by lookahead was "&"
\end{aligned}\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The reason is that `{aligned}` looks ahead for an optional argument and this triggers the building of the table cell, causing an error. The fix proposed in the bug report [latex/3040](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/3040) is simpler than what ended up in `amsmath.sty`:

```
\def\@testopt#1#2{%
  {\ifnum`}=0\fi
  \@ifnextchar[%
    {\ifnum`{=\z@\fi}#1}%
    {\ifnum`{=\z@\fi}#1[#2]}%
}
```

but has one drawback: it introduces a spurious `{}` which could be intrusive in some cases. The idea behind the code is the following: by opening a brace before LaTeX looks ahead for `[`, the next `&` will not immediately end the current cell of the parent environment, thus allowing LaTeX to test whether it is equal to `[`. A similar effect can be seen when comparing

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c}a\meaning&b\end{tabular}
```

with

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c}a{\meaning&}b\end{tabular}
```

The `` \ifnum`}=0\fi `` and `` \ifnum`{=\z@\fi `` are only here so that `\def` doesn't complain that its contents is not balanced in braces. During expansion, they disappear.

The version which ended up in `amsmath.sty` is more complex as it replaces the explicit `{` and `}` of the previous code by `\iffalse{\fi` and `\iffalse}\fi` to avoid the drawback mentioned earlier. Here's the code:

```
\def\alignsafe@testopt#1#2{%
  \relax\iffalse{\fi\ifnum`}=0\fi
  \@ifnextchar[%
    {\let\@let@token\relax \ifnum`{=\z@\fi\iffalse}\fi#1}%
    {\let\@let@token\relax \ifnum`{=\z@\fi\iffalse}\fi#1[#2]}%
}
```

What is more subtle is that using `` \ifnum0=`{\fi `` instead of `\iffalse{\fi` wouldn't work. This can be illustrated by the fact that

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
a\ifnum`{=0\fi&\ifnum`}=0\fi b\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

compiles whereas

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
a\iffalse{\fi&\iffalse}\fi b\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

does not. The reason is explained in appendix D (“Dirty Tricks”) of *The TeXbook* page 385 (see also [*TeX by Topic*](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic), §10.4): when `\iffalse{\fi` is expanded, it increments the master counter whereas `` \ifnum0=`{fi `` does not and it is this master counter which is used for alignment matters (the other counter being the balance counter, which is equally fooled by both). The reason why the expansion of `` \ifnum0=`{fi `` doesn't increment the master counter is that there is no explicit brace in it since after `\ifnum0=` TeX expects a number and so `` `{ `` is converted into a number instead of being a backtick followed by a brace (in fact, the *real* reason why `` `{ `` doesn't increase the master counter is that when TeX reads the `{` after the backtick, it increases the master counter, but when it evaluates `` `{ ``, it decreases it, so it's as if the counter didn't change). The same would be true for `` \romannumeral-`{\space `` but not for `` \@gobble`{ `` (because TeX is not in "reading a number" mode after `\@gobble`).

Here's the table from *The TeXbook* (page 385) showing what happens to which counter when:

[image: Table of changes to the master and balance counters]

Comment: @Philippe: great job! Do you know why there are two different counters? And what would `\@gobble\`{` do to the counters?

Comment: @Bruno: Unfortunately, `\@gobble\`{` globbles the tick so it would act just like a brace. The existence of two counters allows a maximum of flexibility, like hiding things from alignments without creating a group. You can see this with `\begin{tabular}{c|c}\relax\iffalse{\fi\def\macro{2}\meaning&\iffalse}\fi\meaning\macro&\\\end{tabular}` (the `\relax` is here to stop the look ahead for `\omit`; the `\meaning&` is just here to show that a `&` can appear without building up a new cell).

Comment: @Philippe: gobbling the tick was my goal: when expanded, acts like a brace; when passed over, increments the balance counter, but does not change the master counter. Is that right? It would be one way of getting a non-matched brace in a cell. Then I don't know if that's useful.

Comment: @Bruno: the problem is that `\`{` is only a number inside things like `\ifnum`, `\number`, `\romannumeral` etc.; here it's just the two characters `\`` and `{` so it will change both the master and the balance counters. It really acts like an explicit brace.

Comment: @Bruno, @Philippe: Just that I get this straight. The expanded form of `\ifnum0=\`{\fi` doesn't increase the master counter since TeX at no time sees a `{` token with catcode 1; it just sees the number `\`{`. Correct? @Philippe: If yes, you may want to discuss this a bit at the end of your excellent answer.

Comment: @Hendrik: Yes, it is correct and I've added it to the end of the answer.

Comment: @Philippe: Thanks! Four more small points: 1. I don't quite understand "by opening a brace before LaTeX looks ahead for `[` so that it knows that any `&` encountered is not to immediately end the current cell." 2. Is there any reason why at one place there's `0`, and `\z@` at the other? 3. Is there a reason for `\let\@let@token\relax` _not_ being before the `\@ifnextchar`? 4. In short, `\iffalse{\fi\ifnum\`}=0\fi` just increases the master counter and could be put into a macro `\increasemastercounter`, correct?

Comment: @Hendrik: **1.** Without braces, any `&` ends the current cell, as seen in `\begin{tabular}{c|c}a\meaning&b\end{tabular}` compared to `\begin{tabular}{c|c}a{\meaning&b}\end{tabular}`. **2.** The difference is that `\z@` doesn't look for a space after, but as the test is false, it's irrelevant here as far as I can tell. **3.** It's after because `\@let@token` is defined by `\@ifnextchar`. **4.** In an expansion context, yes. Knuth gives a similar example in the TeXbook (page 385).

Comment: @Philippe: Thanks again! **1.** I _essentially_ understood what you meant, but my point was that the sentence is a bit of a grammatical mess, so it's hard to see what "so that it knows" refers to. **2.** So this is just an inconsistency, OK. **3.** Ah, OK, now I understand. Thanks! **4.** What would go wrong in a non-expansion context?

Comment: @Philippe: I just saw that I didn't get it quite straight above: You already pointed me to page 385 in your answer, and there I now read "The master counter
decreases by 1 when TeX evaluates the alphabetic constant `\`{`, and it increases by 1
when TeX evaluates `\`}`, hence the net change is zero when such constants are evaluated." Same effect, but different explanation.

Comment: @Hendrik: I've edited the answer to clarify the grammatical mess and added the precision about the increase/decrease of the master counter with `\`{` (thanks for pointing that out). Concerning **4.**, it's not so much a question of what would go *wrong* than to know that, in a non-expansion context, TeX would only see the macro, so wouldn't change the master or balance counters at that point.

Comment: @Philippe: Thanks! Concerning **4.**: In a non-expansion context, neither `\iffalse{\fi\ifnum\`}=0\fi` nor `\increasemastercounter` change the counters, but the latter is clearer. My point was: Those hacks appear a few times, so it would be worth having them as macros. Maybe `\hiddenbgroup` and `\hiddenegroup` would also be good names?

Comment: It would be nice to have some kind of picture showing exactly what happens to which counter when...

Comment: @SamB: I've added the table from *The TeXbook* showing what happens to the counters.

Answer (score 9):

**On the `\iffalse{\fi` trick again.**

Given a list of the form `\def\foo{\elt{world}\elt{Hello,}\elt{!}}`, I want `\popright\foo` to remove the last element from `\foo` (i.e., yield the same as `\def\foo{\elt{world}\elt{Hello,}}`). It can be done in linear time. The idea is to start with `\edef\foo{\iffalse}\fi`, and end the definition with `\iffalse{\fi}`. In between, each element is wrapped in `\unexpanded`.

```
\catcode`\@=11
\long\protected\def\popright#1{%
    \edef#1{\iffalse}\fi
    \expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\popright@aux
    \expandafter\@gobble #1X}
\long\def\popright@aux#1#2{%
    \ifx X#2%
        \expandafter\popright@end
    \fi
    \unexpanded{\elt{#1}}%
    \popright@aux}
\long\def\popright@end#1\popright@aux{\iffalse{\fi}}
\catcode`\@=12
```

The last element is detected by noting that it is not followed by `\elt`, but by `X`. In the LaTeX3 code, I decided to put something like `{?\iffalse{\fi}\@gobblethree}` instead of `X`, and replace the relatively costly `\ifx` test by `\@gobble#2`, but that just brings a small speed improvement, and the code is rather more obscure. [see `\seq_pop_right:NN` in `source3.pdf`]

Noteworthy is also the fact that D.E.K. himself mentions in the TeXbook (appendix D) that it is probably impossible to do that in TeX. eTeX's `\unexpanded` is necessary for a full solution.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the construction `\expandafter\@gobble\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi`. First `\iffalse}\fi` is expanded and disappears. Then `\@gobble` gobbles everything until it reaches an extra closing brace. A variant of this can maybe be used to implement some form of expandable `\aftergroup` (which would only work with brace groups). I also use it in the following.

We test whether the first token of a given list of tokens is an *explicit* begin group character. Note that using `\futurelet` would not distinguish between an implicit brace `\bgroup` and an explicit brace `{`. Also the solution below is expandable.

So, first a LaTeX code using no package. The trick is to hit the argument, `#1`, with `\string`. We know that initially, `#1` is balanced. If the first token is not a begin group character, then `\string#1` is still balanced after one expansion. On the other hand, if the first token *is* an explicit catcode `1` character, then `\string` converts it to a harmless catcode, and `\string#1` now has an extra end group character (catcode `2`).

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@thirdoffour#1#2#3#4{#3}

\long\def\iffirst@brace#1{%
  \expandafter\@gobble\expandafter{\expandafter{%
      \string#1*%
    }\expandafter \@thirdoffour \expandafter {\iffalse}\fi
  }\@secondoftwo
}
```

We make use of this fact using `\@gobble`, which grabs a brace group and removes it. If the first token was not of catcode `1`, then after `\string` is expanded, the situation looks like

```
\@gobble{{%
    ...*%
  }\expandafter\@thirdoffour\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi
}\@secondoftwo
```

`\@gobble` only leaves `\@secondoftwo`, which is what we want to grab the `false` branch coming afterwards. On the other hand, if the first token is a brace group, then the situation looks like

```
\@gobble{{%
  ...}...*%
}\expandafter\@thirdoffour\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi
}\@secondoftwo
```

Here, `\@gobble` leaves

```
\expandafter\@thirdoffour\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi
}\@secondoftwo
```

We still have an extra closing brace... But `\iffalse}\fi` is expanded and disappears, and `\@thirdoffour` takes the arguments `{}\@secondoftwo{true branch}{false branch}`, and only leaves `{true branch}`.

The star is just some random non-brace token, here so that `\string` does not act on the next (closing brace) token if the argument is empty. Some tests:

```
% For testing purposes only:
\def\test#1{\message{\iffirst@brace{#1}{true}{false}}}
\test{{ab}cd}  \test{a{bc}d}  \test{ {ab}d}  % "true false false"
\test{{}}      \test{ }       \test{}        % "true false false"
```

Initially, I had written the code using the LaTeX3 convention (the `expl3` package). It defines a `\tl_if_first_brace:nTF` equivalent to the above, and also the variants `\tl_if_first_brace:nT` and `\tl_if_first_brace:nF`, which only have a `true branch` or `false branch`. It also defines a *predicate* `\tl_if_first_brace_p:n`, which has no equivalent in "plain" LaTeX2e.

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \tl_if_first_brace:n #1 {p,T,F,TF} {
  \exp_after:wN \use_none:n \exp_after:wN { \exp_after:wN { 
      \token_to_str:N #1 ?
    }\prg_return_true: \exp_after:wN \use_none:nn \exp_after:wN {\if_false:}\fi:
  }\prg_return_false:
}
```

Comment: very nice trick.

Answer (score 7):

A brace trick I found useful is in [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43412/4427) for typesetting continued fractions with a simpler syntax than

```
1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{4}}}
```

that requires keeping track of the nesting; using

```
\xcontfrac{1;2,3,4}
```

seems quite easier. The idea is to loop through the list `2,3,4` and build a token list containing

```
1+
\noexpand\cfrac{1}\iftrue{\else}\fi 2+
  \noexpand\cfrac{1}\iftrue{\else}\fi 3+
    \noexpand\cfrac{1}\iftrue{\else}\fi 4
```

and another one containing

```
    \iffalse{\else}\fi
  \iffalse{\else}\fi
\iffalse{\else}\fi
```

(indenting is added for clarity) so that pasting these to token list and feeding the result to `\edef` builds the desired one, so that finally `\cfrac` can do its job.

Comment: The `l3regex` implementation uses a similar trick to build the result of a regular expression replacement (with two (three) consecutive `\edef` expansions).  An arbitrary token list, say `a{b}#` can be split into individual tokens, but to manipulate those we need to make them into balanced token lists: `a`, `{\iffalse}\fi`, `b`, `\iffalse{\fi}` and `##`. Those are stored in `\toks` registers. The registers are unpacked by a first `\edef`, giving `a{\iffalse}\fi b\iffalse{\fi}##`, and a second `\edef` gives `a{b}#`. Getting it to work for arbitrary tokens is hard :).