# Replace chars with xstring. Catcode problem

Tags: catcodes, xstring

I try to do something like this (minimal example):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{:}{\string&}[\fooo]
    \StrSubstitute{\fooo}{-}{\string\\}[\fooo]
    \tokenize{\fooo}{\fooo}
    \fooo}


\begin{document}


\[\begin{matrix}
    \foo{1:2-2:3}
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

But I it isn't working,
for some reason this is working:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\StrSubstitute{1:2-2:3}{:}{\string&}[\fooo]
\StrSubstitute{\fooo}{-}{\string\\}[\fooo]
\tokenize{\fooo}{\fooo}

\[\begin{matrix}
    \fooo
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

Any Idea on this? I think this is related to catcodes...

Maybe someone also has an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that the `matrix` environment (or rather, the underlying `\halign` TeX primitive) sees `&` while xstring is manipulating it (more precisely, while performing the `\tokenize` step). TeX thinks that this is the end of the cell, inserts the end-of-cell material, including the internal primitive `\endtemplate`, which makes the xstring macros choke. If you want to see this in action, add `\tracingall` before `\tokenize`, and get a confusing output.

So... how do we hide `&` from TeX's inquisitive eyes? It turns out that if TeX sees `&` (or rather, a token with catcode 4, alignment tab) when it thinks that it is within braces, the `&` token is left as it is, and not converted to the end of a cell. Thus for instance `\def\foo{&}` will not make TeX choke when appearing in an alignment: `&` is hidden. On the other hand, `\begin{matrix}abc\string &\end{matrix}` will not show `&`, but a `$` (the first character in the end-of-cell material). For more info on that, see [Philippe Goutet's description of `\alignsafe@testopt`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10371/2707).

Anyways, one solution is to put all of the xstring commands within a brace group, and expand `\fooo` after it: something like

```
\begin{matrix}
  {\StrSubstitute{1:2-3:4}{:}{\string&}[\fooo]
  \StrSubstitute{\fooo}{-}{\string\\}[\fooo]
  \tokenize{\fooo}{\fooo}
  \expandafter}\fooo
\end{matrix}
```

(wrapped in a command if you like). The drawback with this is that we are giving essentially `{}1&2\\3&4` to typeset for TeX, and the empty brace group may affect spacing in some cases. Instead, I'd use "fake" braces `\iffalse{\fi` and `\iffalse}\fi`, which make TeX think that `&` isn't the end of a cell, but which don't insert anything to be typeset. The extra `\relax` in the code below is needed because otherwise TeX, expanding fully the material at the start of the cell, expands `\iffalse{\fi` too early, when it is not yet recording the number of braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
    \relax\iffalse{\fi            % <= here
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{:}{\string&}[\fooo]%
    \StrSubstitute{\fooo}{-}{\string\\}[\fooo]%
    \tokenize{\fooo}{\fooo}%
    \iffalse}\fi                  % <= and there
    \fooo}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{matrix}
    \foo{1:2-2:3}
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

The other answers point to the fact that you don't need the `\tokenize` step if you replace `\string&` by `&` and `\string\\` by `\\` (or `\tabularnewline`), and are careful with expansion. Then, it turns out that `&` is never seen outside braces (only within `\def\...{...&...}` and such), and this is why TeX does not choke.

EDIT2: LaTeX3 has a function similar to `\tokenize` (namely, `\tl_gset_rescan:Nnn` and friends), and they had the same "bug" as `\tokenize` (the fact that the user-provided argument is not always hidden behind braces. That's fixed in the svn as of December 18 (today).

Comment: Thanks for your great explication! I got an Idea of the Problem and your proposed solution. It is working, as far as I can tell. Will do some more tests tomorrow. I'm just wondering if it would be possible to dedect a normally typed new line and replace it with \\

Comment: It is impossible to detect new lines reliably: they are converted to spaces very early on. There was a question some time ago about how to define a macro delimited by line breaks, but I can't find it :(.

Comment: thx, I thought that would be possible, because  I was thinking that environments like verbatim also have to do something like that. (They don't need an explicit line break with \\)

Comment: @someonr: it is possible to detect new lines _unreliably_. If you really want that, you can ask a separate question: surely someone will know where to point you to. The details are a little bit messy.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code in which `:` and `,` are replaced with a `&` :

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
    \saveexpandmode\expandarg
    \StrSubstitute{\noexpand#1}:&[\fooo]%
    \StrSubstitute\fooo,&[\fooo]%
    \StrSubstitute\fooo-{\noexpand\\}[\fooo]%
    \restoreexpandmode\[\begin{matrix}\fooo\end{matrix}\]}
\begin{document}
\foo{1:2-2:3-x,y}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should use `\unexpanded{#1}` if you want to prevent the expansion of the user's argument. Otherwise, only the first token is notexpanded.

Comment: No. As the manual says, only the first token is expanded when `\expandarg` mode. Therefore, a simple `\noexpand` prevents this expansion.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read the xstring manual, I thought it woule be an edef. --- IIRC, you're the `xstring` maintainer. You should add `\relax\iffalse{\fi\ifnum\`\}=0\fi` at the start of the definition for `\tokenize` and `\ifnum\`\{=0\fi\iffalse}\fi` at the end (or similar, see Philippe Goutet's answer I link to in my answer).

Comment: Arguments are expanded with `\edef` when under `\fullexpandarg` mode. For `\tokenize`, you see that it is just a simple way to use `\scantokens`. Though I read the link you suggested, I do not see why I should add something to the definition of `\tokenize`, both at its begining and at its end.

Comment: In the current state, `\tokenize{\foo}{&}` will fail in an alignment context because `&` is not "hidden behind braces" (the master counter is zero when `&` is read). The solution which changes the least amount of code is to add `\iffalse{\fi` and `\iffalse}\fi` to `\tokenize`, so that unsuspecting users doing `\tokenize\foo{&}` will not trigger TeX's wrath: the master counter is then 1 when `&` is read. See my email for more details, and other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following one:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
\begingroup
\catcode`\&=12
\noexpandarg
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{-}{\tabularnewline}[\fooo]
\expandarg
    \StrSubstitute{\fooo}{:}{&}[\fooo]
\expandafter\endgroup
    \fooo}


\begin{document}


\[\begin{matrix}
    \foo{1:2-2:3-4444:55555}
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your Code works good. What would I do if I need more than one Symbol replaced by &?

Comment: @someonr: I can't understand the question. Can you provide a small example.

Comment: never mind, thx for your answer. I think I just understood the problem, thx to the answer from Bruno Le Floch.