# Continued fractions

Tags: fractions

How do I make this in LaTeX? I keep losing track of the brackets.

[image]

Comment: Do you know about the `\cfrac` macro provided by the `amsmath` package?

Comment: I don't have any packages, I use latex2png.com, as my teacher told me to use it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think it is (seems to be)

Comment: Well it is the basic LaTeX, and I can make this up to the third fraction, until I lose sight of my brackets. Just wondered if one the geniuses here could make it hehe :-)

Comment: `\cfrac` works at that site, I just tried

Comment: Checked with `y = 2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{1+\dots}}}` on that site, it works

Comment: And no I don't know anything about the more complex functions and codes in LaTeX - I'm a newbie here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ok, it's LaTeX then, it does even know `\section{Foo}` ;-)

Comment: See [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43412/4427) for being able to use the friendlier syntax `e=\xcontfrac{2;1,2,1,4,1,1,6+\cfraccdots}` (in math mode, of course).

Answer (score 25):

The following code is "full LaTeX":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\cfrac" macro
\begin{document}
\[
\mathrm{e}=
2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+
  \cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{6+
  \cdots\vphantom{\cfrac{1}{1}} }}}}}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want, you can copy and paste the math part -- the stuff between `\[` and `\]` -- into `latex2png.com`.

Comment: I am SO grateful! Thank you very much Mico (and all others helping me out)

Comment: I learned something new today as well: the existence of the site `latex2png.com`!

Comment: Our teacher told us we had to use it in our assignments, glad we could learn each other something. I think it's really nice to get into such a respectful and friendly community

Answer (score 6):

Or, using no packages:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$e=
2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{6+\cdots}}}}}}}
}
$
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Although `\cfrac` works better, this seemed to be what you were originally trying to get.

The copyable code for the website would be:

```
e=2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{6+\cdots}}}}}}}}
```