# Finite continued fraction with dots in-between

Tags: fractions

I found this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346398/continued-fractions) on how to typeset continued fractions. The form I want is the following: [image] with dots in between as illustrated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43402/how-to-lower-last-term-in-a-continued-fraction-after-a-diagonal-row-of-dots/43412#43412 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
a_0 + \frac{1\kern6em}{\displaystyle
  a_1 + \frac{1\kern5em}{\displaystyle
    a_2 +\stackunder{}{\ddots\stackunder{}{\displaystyle
      {}+ \frac{1}{\displaystyle
        a_{n-1} + \frac{1}{a_n}}}
}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]