# Latex for Continued Fractions

Tags: fractions

[image]

The current formula I have is:

```
\begin{displaymath}
1 = \frac{1}{\cfrac{2}{1-\cfrac{1}{3}}}
\end{displaymath}
```

How should I proceed further?

Comment: See `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346398/continued-fractions`.

Comment: Thanks for this! I don't understand it fully. Can you help me do it for one more term?

Comment: The next term is a bit strange.  Continued fractions don't normally have a/b/c.  Are you sure about your notation?

Comment: Thank you, @Teepeemm. Yes, the notation is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se if the following is what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
1 =  \frac{\tfrac{1}{2}}{1-\cfrac{\tfrac{1}{3}}{1-\cfrac{\tfrac{1}{4}}{1-\cfrac{\tfrac{1}{5}}{1-\cfrac{\tfrac{1}{6}}{1-\tfrac{1}{7}}}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This seems quite similar to the picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\-}{{}-{}}% local redefinition, harmless
1=\;
\begin{array}[t]{*{10}{c}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\dfrac{\kern1pt 1 \kern1pt}{2\mathstrut}} \\
\cline{1-3}
1 & \- & 1 \\
\cline{3-3}\noalign{\kern1pt}
&& 3 \\
\cline{3-5}
&& 1 & \- & 1 \\
\cline{5-5}\noalign{\kern1pt}
&&&& 4 \\
\cline{5-7}
&&&& 1 & \- & 1 \\
\cline{7-7}\noalign{\kern1pt}
&&&&&& 5 \\
\cline{7-9}
&&&&&& 1 & \- & 1 \\
\cline{9-9}\noalign{\kern1pt}
&&&&&&&& 6 \\[-2ex]
&&&&&&&&& \ddots
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]