# how to add more white space over symbols in a nested fraction?

Tags: fractions

I am writing some complicated formulas that involve several layers of fractions.

Example:

```
\begin{displaymath}
\scalebox{2.5}[3]%
{$
1+\frac{1^2}{2+\frac{3^2}{2+\frac{5^2}{2+\frac{7^2}{2+\frac{9^2}{2+\cdots}}}}}
$}
\end{displaymath}
```

but the visual result, although readable, could be improved with some white space over all the squared odd terms. How would I achieve that? The vertical scaling of `\scalebox` does not help since I guess that the spacing between the fraction line and the exponent under it is too close to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Warning: Mico's solution is better (see below). With mine, the edges of the fractional expressions are not perfectly aligned on the right.</sup>

You could use `\dfrac` and `\mathstrut`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{displaymath}
        1+\dfrac{1^2}{2+\dfrac{3^{\mathstrut 2}}{2+\dfrac{5^{\mathstrut 2}}{2+\dfrac{7^{\mathstrut 2}}{2+\dfrac{9^{\mathstrut 2}}{2+\cdots}}}}}
    \end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I did not know about \mathstrut

Comment: @marcotrevi Look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41185/strutting-around-whats-the-difference-between-strut-mathstrut-and-vphantom

Comment: @marcotrevi Thank you for accepting my answer but Mico's one is better, see the end of the fraction lines, they are not perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 10):

Load the `amsmath` package and use its `\cfrac` ("continued fraction") macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \cfrac macro
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
1+\cfrac{1^2}{2+\cfrac{3^2}{2+\cfrac{5^2}{2+\cfrac{7^2}{2+\cfrac{9^2}{2+\cdots}}}}}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

The main difference to a `\dfrac`-based solution is that, with `\cfrac`, the right-hand edge of the fractional expressions is nice and vertical, which is not the case if `\dfrac` is used repeatedly.

Comment: @CarLaTeX And you might enjoy a simplified syntax for continued fractions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43412/4427

Comment: Great! It's not super neat with other formulas though

Comment: @marcotrevi - Please give an example or two of "other formulas" which don't look "super neat" when using `\cfrac`. (It's not easy to respond to a generic, non-specific comment...)

Comment: @egreg Of course, a LaTeX3 solution must make an appearance!

Comment: @Mico I got an undeserved tick, perhaps the OP intends to use `\mathstrut` in his original way of writing the formula...

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Thanks, but don't fret or worry about it. These things do tend to even out in the medium to long term. In the past, I'm sure that some of my answers received ticks when others were at least as deserving. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are printing more continued fractions in your document then you can define the macro `\cfraction` which gives you more compendious source:

```
\def\cfraction{\def\cfracE{}\cfracA}
\def\cfracA#1+#2{#1\ifx#2\relax +\cdots\cfracE \else 
   + \bgroup \xdef\cfracE{\cfracE\egroup} \strut #2\expandafter\cfracB \fi}
\def\cfracB#1\over{#1\over \displaystyle\cfracA}


$$
\cfraction 
1 + 1^2 \over 2 + 3^2 \over 2 + 5^2 \over 2 + 7^2 \over 2 + 9^2 \over 2 + \relax
$$

\bye
```

Comment: There's no drifting of the fraction lines if you add `\kern-\nulldelimiterspace` after `\egroup`

Comment: OK, but the "drifting of fraction lines" is more aesthetic from my point of view.