# Defining environments that do not start a new group

Tags: align, environments

In the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, environ}

\NewEnviron{hidden}{}
\def\hide#1{}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  X &= Y \\
  % \begin{hidden}  % DOES NOT WORK
    &=Y_{1}%
  \\ &\leq Y_{2}\\%
  % \end{hidden}
  \hide{&=Y_{3}\\&=Y_{4}}
    &\le Z
\end{align*}
\begin{hidden}
  Some more tests
\end{hidden}
\end{document}
```

I define a command and an environment to hide a certain part of the document (this is a simplification, my use case is a bit more complicated). The command works in all situation including an `align` environment. However, my new environment does not work inside `align` or similar commands. This is probably because `\begin{hidden}` `\end{hidden}` opens and closes a group within `aligned` which creates problems. Is there a way to create a dummy environment that does not create groups, much like a command seemingly does not.

Comment: even if you stopped your environment forming a group it would fail because each alignment cell between `&...&` or `&...\\ ` is a group so whatever you set in `\begin{hidden}` will be lost at the first `&` (you will see same in `tabular` or `array` and similar environments, not just `align`

Comment: Thanks David. I am not sure I get your point 100%. Does this apply to commands as well (like my `\hide`)? If not, I don't understand why an environment would be different from a command, except for the introduction of the new group.

Comment: the `{}` in the command syntax automatically "hide" the `&` so as you skip over hat section the alignment cell does not end. For nested environemnts you have to work a bit harder (using the same special groups that are used so you can nest array or aligned inside align without the `&` ending the outer alignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want to *add* a group so that when you skip over `&` you do not end the alignment cell and so end the group where you started hiding.

[image]

This version does not cope with nested environments, but works here and shows teh basic scheme.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, environ}

\def\hidden{{\ifnum0=`}\fi
\xhidden}
\def\xhidden#1\end#2{\ifnum0=`{\fi}\end{hidden}}% probably ought to check that #2 is "hidden"


\def\hide#1{}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  X &= Y \\
   \begin{hidden}  % DOES NOT WORK
    &=Y_{1}%
  \\ &\leq Y_{2}\\%
   \end{hidden}
  \hide{&=Y_{3}\\&=Y_{4}}
    &\le Z
\end{align*}
\begin{hidden}
  Some more tests
\end{hidden}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! I want to modify this to cope with nested environments. But I admit I don't fully understand the solution (my LaTeX-fu is limited). What does `\ifnum0={\fi}` do in both `\hidden` and `\xhidden`?

Comment: Found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9897/showcase-of-brace-tricks-egroup-iffalse-fi-etc) which shows that this syntax starts and ends a group that could contain `&` in the argument. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Based on David's answer. Here's my attempt to make things work for nested environments.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, etoolbox}

\def\hide#1{} % or \def\hide#1{#1} to not hide it.

% Essentially flips "\begin{hidden}#1\end{hidden}" to "\begin{hidden}\end{hidden} \hide{#1}"
\def\hidden{{\ifnum0=`}\fi\xhidden\argend}%
\def\xhidden#1\argend#2\end#3{%
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#3}{hidden}%
{\ifnum0=`{\fi}\end{hidden}\hide{#1#2}}{\xhidden#1#2\end{#3}\argend}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  X &= Y \\
  \begin{hidden}
    &=Y_{1}%
    \\ &\leq Y_{2}\\%
    \begin{matrix}
      A & BC
    \end{matrix}\\
  \end{hidden}
  \hide{&=Y_{3}\\&=Y_{4}}
    &\le Z
\end{align*}
\begin{hidden}
  \begin{center}
    Hello
  \end{center}
  Some more tests
\end{hidden}
\end{document}
```