# enumerate/item as environments

Tags: environments, enumerate

In the following MWE

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\newenvironment{myitem}{\item}{}%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
    \begin{myitem} Item 1 \end{myitem}  % This is the only difference
    \item Item 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

% even this works!!!!
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
    \myitem Item 1 \endmyitem  % This is the only difference
    \item Item 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The output of the first part is correct, but the output of my verbose `myitem` environment (which should just replicate `\item`) is missing the number on the second line. EDIT: Any idea why this is happening? Note that if I add any text in the outer `\item`, everything works as expected (the inner enumerate starting on a new line).

In my real use-case, I have to execute some code at the beginning and end of each item, which is why I adopted the use of an environment.

EDIT: thanks for the suggestions regarding other ways to resolve this. But I am also quite interested to learn why the environment approach is failing.

EDIT2:
I found out that I can replicate the wrong behaviour with.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate}
    \begingroup \item test 1 \endgroup
    \item item 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

So clearly the fact that the environments are starting groups around the `\item` is the issue. I thought I could change the definition of my environment as follows:

```
\newenvironment{myitem}{\endgroup\item\begingroup}{}%
```

To cause the group to be created outside `\item`, but then I get the error

```
\begin{enumerate} on input line 15 ended by \end{myitem}.
```

Comment: Have a look if the `getitems` package might be helpful for your real use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution from one of my own previous [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571391/defining-environments-that-do-not-start-a-new-group). Sorry for the noise.

I just needed to define the environment like this.

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\myitem{{\ifnum0=`}\fi\@myitem\@argend}%
\long\def\@myitem#1\@argend#2\end#3{%
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#3}{myitem}%
{\ifnum0=`{\fi}\end{myitem}\@myrealitem{#1#2}}{\@myitem#1#2\end{#3}\@argend}}
\def\@myrealitem#1{\item #1}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

I've used another approach to get what you want.

The code defined in `\itemBeginCode` and `\itemEndCode` is executed before and after each `\myitem` within the `myenumerate` environment.

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\itemBeginCode}{\emph{(start)}}
\newcommand{\itemEndCode}{\emph{(end)}}

\newtoggle{myfirstitem}
\newenvironment{myenumerate}{%
    \toggletrue{myfirstitem}%
    \begin{enumerate}%
}{%
    \itemEndCode% for the last item
    \end{enumerate}%
}

\newcommand{\myitem}{%
    \iftoggle{myfirstitem}{}{\itemEndCode}% if not the first item
    \item%
    \togglefalse{myfirstitem}%
    \itemBeginCode%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
    \begin{myenumerate}
    \myitem Item 1
    \myitem Item 2
    \end{myenumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually would like to keep using the environment as it has other advantages in my case. I am just wondering why using the environment has this weird behaviour.